# How to get ngram frequency lists from Google's dataset?

Tags: dictionary

Is it possible to download this dataset somehow? I get linked to [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/google-books-ngrams-2020), but there is also the [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/). [Working With Google Ngrams: A Data-Wrangling Tale](https://economicsfromthetopdown.com/2020/10/19/working-with-google-ngrams-a-data-wrangling-tale/) tells the story that it's no longer really possible to download it I guess, but can't totally tell.

The original [Google blog post](https://blog.research.google/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html?m=1) from 2006 says "the data belongs to you" and seems to have released it for download at some point. The [python ngram downloader](https://pypi.org/project/google-ngram-downloader/) project *seems* like it will download it, but not sure if the data is too large to fit on a laptop or something, or *what* it does.

Any tips or suggestions on how to get these word frequency lists would be great.